# How to make radio buttons that show and hide inputs work within a jquery cloned div?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like for the radio selection to work within the cloned div. The div will be cloned indefinitely, each clone requires a new selection.

How do I get the radio selection buttons within each div to point to only the items within their div?

As it stands now, the selection clones but when the different items are selected nothing happens.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

HTML:

```
<form>
<div id="clonedForm_1" class="clonedForm">
    <div class="addSomeJazz">
    <label name="btn1">Selection 1
        <input type="radio" name="select" class="btn1" value="Selection 1" />
    </label>
    <label name="btn2">Selection 2
        <input type="radio" name="select" class="btn2" value="Selection 2" />
    </label>
    <label name="btn3">Selection 3
        <input type="radio" name="select" class="btn3" value="Selection 3" />
    </label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="selection1 hidden" id="selection1_1">
        <label name="text1" class="hideMe">Something thoughtful:
            <input type="text" name="text1" class="hideMe" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="selection2 hidden" id="selection2_1">
        <label name="select1" class="hideMe">Select one of these:
            <select class="hideMe">
                <option>Select this</option>
                <option>Or this</option>
                <option>Or maybe this</option>
                <option>DO NOT select this</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="selection2 hidden" id="selection3_1">
        <label name="checkyboxy" class="hideMe">What applies:
            <input type="checkbox" name="thechecks" value="cool" class="hideMe" />I am cool
            <input type="checkbox" name="thechecks" value="interesting" class="hideMe" />I am interesting
            <input type="checkbox" name="thechecks" value="funny" class="hideMe" />I am funny</label>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="cloneMe" value="Add Another Entry" />
<input type="button" id="deleteMe" value="Get rid of that last one" />
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $('#cloneMe').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedForm').length,
            newNum = new Number(num + 1),
            newElem = $('#clonedForm_' + num).clone().attr('id', 'clonedForm_' +         newNum).fadeIn('slow');
        newElem.find('.selection1').attr('id', 'selection1_' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.selection2').attr('id', 'selection2_' + newNum);
        newElem.find('.selection3').attr('id', 'selection3_' + newNum);
        newElem.find(":input[type='radio']").attr('name', 'select' + newNum);
        newElem.find(".hideMe").addClass('hidden');

        $('#clonedForm_' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#deleteMe').attr('disabled', false);
    });
    $('#deleteMe').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedForm').length;
        $('#clonedForm_' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
            if (num - 1 === 1) $('#deleteMe').attr('disabled', true);
        });
    });

    $('#deleteMe').attr('disabled', true);
});

$('.btn1').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedForm').length;

    $('#selection1_' + num).show();
    $('#selection2_' + num).hide();
    $('#selection3_' + num).hide();
});
$('.btn2').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedForm').length;
    $('#selection1_' + num).hide();
    $('#selection2_' + num).show();
    $('#selection3_' + num).hide();
});
$('.btn3').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedForm').length;
    $('#selection1_' + num).hide();
    $('#selection2_' + num).hide();
    $('#selection3_' + num).show();
});
});
```

Here is a link to an example I set up on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieKatie/pqD8s/

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please do, even if it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is your event handlers. I changed it to use event delegation and traversal functions to find the element to hide and show. There were a few other small changes, and there are still other optimizations that could be done (for example, I don't think dealing with the `id`s is gaining you anything).

http://jsfiddle.net/p9YKt/

Here's the important part:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn1', function () {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.clonedForm');

    $container.find('.selection1').show();
    $container.find('.selection2').hide();
    $container.find('.selection3').hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn2', function () {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.clonedForm');

    $container.find('.selection1').hide();
    $container.find('.selection2').show();
    $container.find('.selection3').hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '.btn3', function () {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.clonedForm');

    $container.find('.selection1').hide();
    $container.find('.selection2').hide();
    $container.find('.selection3').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jason P has the ticket - event bubbling.

I've made it a little dryer. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UB5EL/1/

1) Update your HTML a bit to give the radio buttons values that correlate to your toggled form elements.

```
<label name="btn1">Selection 1
    <input type="radio" name="select" class="btn1" value="selection1" />
</label>
<label name="btn2">Selection 2
    <input type="radio" name="select" class="btn2" value="selection2" />
</label>
<label name="btn3">Selection 3
    <input type="radio" name="select" class="btn3" value="selection3" />
</label>
```

2) Wrap all of your toggled form elements in a container to make hiding them all at once easier. I put them in a `<div class="selections">` in the example.

3) Then change the end of you JS so that you're only using one `change` handler instead of three click handlers. Figure out what to do with the `change` event based on the value of the radio button that was changed.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {

    var $container = $(this).closest('.clonedForm'),
        target = $(this).val();

    $container.find('.selections').find('div').hide();
    // or skip adding the div.selections and use:
    // $container.find('.selection1, .selection2, .selection3 ').hide();

    $container.find('.'+target).show();

});
```

Comment: If there were more than one radio inputs on the page, could I add a class to those inputs and then use `$(document).on('change', 'input.class', function () {`?

Comment: Yes, or you can change the bubbling scope by changing `$(document)` to `$('#TheIdOfTheFormYouCareAbout).on('change',...)`

Comment: I can't seem to get the hide portion to work on my actual page. I'll keep trying but in the meantime the step by step of @Jason P 's version works like a charm.